# How can I check whether a cast will result in overflow or underflow of the target type?

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a  function in the Standard Library / Boost that will check whether a cast will result in overflow/underflow of the target type? For example:

```
unsigned value = static_cast<unsigned>(12.3); // this should pass (lossy but no overflow)
unsigned value = static_cast<unsigned>(1E123); // this should fail
unsigned value = static_cast<unsigned>(-2); // this should also fail
```

Does somethign like this exist? For the above examples the feature might have functionality similar to this:

```
template <typename Source, typename Target>
bool checkNoOverflow(const Source value)
{
  return value >= std::numeric_limits<Target>::lowest() && value <= std::numeric_limits<Target>::max();
}
```

The above is just a simplified example, which would fail on corner-cases such as this:

```
unsigned value = static_cast<unsigned>(-0.1); // valid, result is 0
```

To be clear, I'm not asking about how to write a function that would work for all cases, but rather I'm after existing functionality in the Standard Library or boost that does this for me.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`boost::numeric_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html).

Comment: @SeanCline brilliant, thanks! Please put it as the answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such function exists in the C++ standard library. That leaves a few options:

---

## Option #1: `boost::numeric_cast`

If you have access to Boost, then [`boost::numeric_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/improved_numeric_cast__.html) should do exactly what you want. It will perform a conversion between two numeric types unless the conversion would go outside the range of the target type. In such cases, a [`boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/boost_numericconversion/numeric_converter_policy_classes.html#numeric_conversion_bad_numeric_cast) exception is thrown.

---

### Option #2: `gsl::narrow()`

Alternatively, [`gsl::narrow`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_narrow) is a good option. I'd consider it preferable to Boost if you are OK with bringing [GSL](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/) into your project.

---

### Option #3: Roll your own.

If you were curious about implementing your own conversion, you can take a look at *The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition* by Bjarne Stroustrup ([ISBN 978-0321563842](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840)).

In Chapter 11.5, he defines a `narrow_cast` as such:

```
template<class Target, class Source>
Target narrow_cast(Source v)
{
   auto r = static_cast<Target>(v); // convert the value to the target type
   if (static_cast<Source>(r)!=v)
      throw runtime_error("narrow_cast<>() failed");
   return r;
}
```

This implementation is quite bare and doesn't go quite as far as Boost's does, but could conceivably be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: Anyone stumbling upon this: the condition is not enough as `static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<int>(X))` does not modify the value. It also needs explicitly checking for sign mismatch when Source and Target signedness is different.